# How do I use PHP arrays for my purposes?

Tags: php, arrays, echo, external

I'm making a website for a music promotion company. The website contains an individual page for each promoted artist; in which their upcoming events appear. There is also a seperate 'events' page.

I was wondering how to create and use arrays so that I could update any upcoming events in one place and for the information to be echoed out on these two seperate pages.

Also, on the events page all of the artists' events will need to be echoed out in chronological order.

Is this the right way of approaching it?

```
 <?php
$donevents = array();
$donevents[101] = array (
    "venue" = "The Moon Club",
    "date" = "5th December 2013",
    "link" = "www.candyratrecords.com"
);
$donevents[102] = array (
    "venue" = "Chapel Arts Centre",
    "date" = "8th August 2013",
    "link" = "www.chapelarts.co.uk"
);
?>
```

Comment: Why not use a database ?

Comment: If you can't use a database and want to store everything in an array, I would store the `date` as a `DateTime` object or at least as `yyyy-mm-dd`. It would make it much easier to sort all events by date and you can format it to any output you want when listing it.

Answer (score 2):

One Little Character Makes Such A Difference (TM):

```
  $donevents[101] = array (
   "venue" => "The Moon Club",
   "date" => "5th December 2013",
   "link" => "www.candyratrecords.com"
  );
```

[Check out the PHP manual on Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Also, it's very bad design to store *events* in program code.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you say "RTFM". It is exceedingly rude. I am editing this for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just a bit bored of questions when answer can be found in the same entitled chapter (as the question is) of the manual. Edit it, as you like.

Comment: I absolutely understand and agree with what you mean, ern0. The best things to do are down vote, or simply not answer. Kudos for taking a shot at an answer, anyway. And for the record, I've made my share of rude comments on things like this, too!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a database, a CSV file may be a good alternative to keep your data separate from your code. Look into using PHP's functions for reading CSV files into arrays, and you can store your file above the webroot so that it can't be publicly accessed.

Using a CSV file will make it much easier to maintain your data if using an actual database is not an option.